# How does this code work? Includes a lambda

Tags: python

Could any one explain the flow of this program by giving an example?

```
id_ = lambda x:x 
// would return the number (id_(1) would return 1)

zero=map(number,0)//should return number= lambda 0: lambda 0:f(0)
```

So I am not able to interpret:

```
number = lambda x: lambda f=id_: f(x)

plus = lambda x: lambda y: y + x

id_ = lambda x: x
number = lambda x: lambda f=id_: f(x)
zero, one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine = map(number, range(10))
plus = lambda x: lambda y: y + x
minus = lambda x: lambda y: y - x
times = lambda x: lambda y: y * x
divided_by = lambda x: lambda y: y / x
```

Calculations using functions:

```
one(plus(one()))

> 2
```

Answer (score 3):

```
number():
 - expects a number "A"
 - returns a function "F" that expects a single argument function (or if not provided it uses "id_" by default)
```

When both arguments are provided the function `number()` gets evaluated and applies the function `F` to the number `A`

```
# Example 1: returns only 3 (applies "id_" by default)
print(number(3)())
```

Prints:

```
3
```

And when a function is provided:

```
def inc(x):
    return x + 1

# Example 2: applies a single argument function to the number 3
print(number(3)(inc))
```

Which returns:

```
4
```

So now the second function you are interested in:

```
plus():
 - expects a number
 - returns a function that accept another number
```

When both arguments are provided the function is evaluated and returns their sum.

```
# Example:
print(plus(3)(4))
```

Prints:

```
7
```

Using the example you used in the comments:

```
one(plus(one()))
```

Starting from the innermost expression we get:

1. `one() == 1` because `one() == number(1)(f=id_) == _id(1)`
2. Second call to `plus(1)` would return `lambda y: y+1`

Applied to the result from first step, `plus(one()) == plus(1) == lambda y: y+1`

So it means that `plus(one())` is (in other words: "returns") itself a function and is equivalent to:

```
def plus_one(y):
   return y + 1
```

3. Last step:

`one(plus(one())) == one(plus_one) == number(1)(f=plus_one) == plus_one(1) == 1 + 1 == 2`

If the lambda syntax bothers you, you can rewrite them for increased clarity (?) into full functions accordingly:

```
def id_(x):
    return x

def number(x):
    def inner(f=id_):
        return f(x)

    return inner

def one(f=id_):
    return f(1)

def plus(x):
    def add_to_x(y):
        return y + x

    return add_to_x

add_one = plus(one())

assert one() == number(1)(f=id_) == id_(1) == 1

assert add_one(2) == plus(1)(2) == 3

assert plus(one())(4) == plus(1)(4) == 5

assert one(plus(one())) == one(add_one) == 2
```

Comment: so this is what I understood.

Comment: so this is what I understood.

say, one(plus(one()))

1. First call to one() would return 1
would compute to number=lambda 1: lambda f=1 (id_ gets called)

2. Second call to plus(1) would return lambda y:y+1
would compute to plus = lambda 1: lambda y:y+1

3. one(lambda y:y+1) would return 2
would compute to number = lambda 1: lambda:f(1)

Is it correct way to interpret?

Comment: Thanks a lot Christophe. :)

People like you make this community great and gives hope to beginners.